# How to get CDATA content into UIWebView in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, cdata

I am not understanding how to get the content of CDATA, I

```
NSString* htmlString = [self getnerateFormattedString:details]; 
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myWebsite.com"]];


-(NSString*) getnerateFormattedString:(TrackDetails*) details
{
    NSString* htmlString = @"";
    htmlString = @"<html><head><title><style type=\"text/css\">a {color: red}</style>";
    htmlString = [htmlString stringByAppendingString:@"</title></head><body style='background-color: transparent;'> "];

if (atrackDetails.trackTitle != nil)
{
    htmlString = [htmlString stringByAppendingString:@"<div align='center' >"];
    htmlString = [htmlString stringByAppendingString:@"<font size='4'>"];
    htmlString = [htmlString stringByAppendingString:details.trackTitle];
    htmlString = [htmlString stringByAppendingString:@"</b></font></div><br>"];
}
htmlString = [htmlString stringByAppendingString:@"<table width=300px cellpadding=5 cellspacing=5 border=0 align='center' height=10px> "];
```

Like this I am loading using loadHTMLString. But I don't know how to get CDATA Content to load webView.

Please Help Me,
Thank you,
Madan Mohan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have cdata code with html content

When you parse the Xml like this, shown below,

dataString =[dataString stringByAppendingString:@""];

dataString=[dataString stringByAppendingString:@"cdata code with html content for example"

dataString =[dataString stringByAppendingString:@""];

You will get this --> Only Html code that u can pass to method which it can dispaly in webview.
Pass this string to loadHTMLString method in webView